# How to find the distance travelled by a pendulum powered car?

Tags: energy-conservation, home-experiment, dissipation

I'm having trouble finding an equation that find the distance travelled by a pendulum powered car based on the weight of the pendulum bob, the length of the pendulum and the angle where the pendulum is dropped.

I have made a simple pendulum powered car which I assume is powered by the momentum of the pendulum. The car frame is equipped with 4 wheels 2 in the front and back, in the exact midpoint of the frame lies 2 metal rods that hold up the pendulum. Additionally, the car is equipped with a braking system that prevents the car from going backwards.

I have tried combining Newton's third law, Conservation of momentum, and inertia but yet the distance is always either far off or close. The close value I assume to be theoretically correct, and the value obtained by experiment have uncertainty.

Comment: Please add the description of your car design, since there are several possibilities of how pendulum motion is converted into energy, and what the car does with it (e.g., it could simply oscillate as the pendulum swings back and force, but it might also convert pendulum motion in electric energy to steadily move forward).

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my post with the description of the car

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.instructables.com/Pendulum-Car/)? Could you show your calculation?

Comment: Roughly yes, but with 4 wheels and 2 supports to hold up the pendulum

Comment: There is probably some dissipation - could you show in your post how you calculate the distance traveled? And how is it off: is it always smaller than predicted?

Comment: There are 2 formulations that I have tried, one involves the variable t for the time until the pendulum stops oscillating, and the other one involves inertia.

x=t(m2/m1(sqrt(2g(l-lcostheta))+1/2gsinthetat)

m2 is the weight of the pendulum and m1 is the weight of the car, for t I have to observe myself.

x = (2Mplsintheta)/2(I1/R1^2+I2/R2^2)+M+Mp

Where Mp is the mass of the pendulum, I1 and R1 is used to calculate the inertia of the front wheel and l2 and R2 for the back wheel and M is the weight of the car.

X is the distance travelled.